# Ionic android and ios CSS issue

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am facing a problem of CSS in ionic application in android.
The problem is that CSS is not working in Android phone.
For example) When I execute in Samsung Galaxy S5, the css is working correctly(See Screenshot 1).
But when I execute Samsung Galaxy Note 2, it is not working(Screenshot 2).

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

As you can see these 2 screenshot, you can find that the background image size is different and also label margins are not same.
Why this problem happened?
Somebody said that it was related to a android web browser. So I have added "crosswalker" plugin in order to upgrade webview.
But it was same.
How can I solve this problem? Please teach me if anybody already experienced.

PS : The codes are following as below:
[html]

```
<ion-view view-title="Log_in" class="user_reg static-bg ionic">  
  <ion-content scroll="false">
    <div class="login_form_container" layout="column" layout-align="" style="padding-top:65px;">
      <div class="signup_btn_back font-raleway" ng-click="backTo()">
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i> Back
      </div>
      <form class="reg_form" id="login_form" ng-submit="login_user(user)">
        <div layout="column" layout-align="left center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
          <div class="row">
            <a ng-click="show_forgot_pass_pop()" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="col col-67 reg_link form_txt"><label class="reg_link_font font-bold font-white font-raleway">
                Forgot password?</label></a>

            <a ng-click="signup()" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="col reg_link form_txt" style="text-align:right;"><label class="reg_link_font font-bold font-white font-raleway">
                Sign Up</label></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="textboxholder button-only-border">
          <div class="textboxcontainer">
            <input type="text" class="form form_text font-raleway"  placeholder="Email Address" ng-model="user.email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="textboxholder button-only-border">
          <div class="textboxcontainer">
            <input type="password" class="form form_text font-raleway" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
          </div>
        </div>      
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center end">
            <button class="button button-common form_btn_cyan form_btn font-raleway" type="submit">Log In!</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>  
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[CSS]

```
.user_reg {
    /*background-image: url('../img/sign_in_bg2.png');*/
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
 .static-bg{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: url('../img/bg-static-onboard.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.textboxholder{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-width: 1px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.button-only-border{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border: 1px solId #FFF;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.textboxcontainer{
      padding-bottom: 5px;
}
    background-color: rgba(0, 0 ,0, 0.5);
    color: #FFF !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 5px !important;
}
.font-raleway{
  font-family: "Raleway" !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to css property background-size: cover. As per w3schools(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp), background-size:cover scales the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. And Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area.

So instead of using background-size:cover, use "background-size:100% 100%;" to set full size background.

Comment: It might be due to responsive design, ionic might have set different text-align property of css based on device size. You can set the "text-align:center !important;" for textbox to override the ionic css for same

Comment: @TimRogers is your issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely have to do with your android version. As from Android 4.4.3 the webview component has got a big upgrade, supporting much more CSS and HTML options. More info about that [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview).

When using custom CSS, your best option would be to limit the app to API level 19 and higher. You would still be able to target 75% of the devices this way.